# Run cforest with controls = cforest_unbiased() using caret package

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I would like to run an unbiased cforest using the caret package. Is this possible?

```
tc <- trainControl(method="cv",
               number=f,
               index=indexList,
               savePredictions=T,
               classProbs = TRUE,
               summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)
createCfGrid <- function(len, data) {
    g = createGrid("cforest", len, data)
    g = expand.grid(.controls = cforest_unbiased(mtry = 5, ntree = 1000))
    return(g)
}
set.seed(1)
(cfMatFit <- train(as.factor(f1win) ~ .,
                   data=df,
                   method="cforest",
                   metric="ROC",
                   trControl=tc,
                   tuneGrid = createCfGrid))
```

The error is `Error in as.character.default(<S4 object of class "ForestControl">) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector`

This is because cforest_control() can not be coerced into a data frame. The function does work if I use:

```
...
g = expand.grid(.mtry = 5)
...
```

However if I want to change ntree, this has no effect:

```
...
g = expand.grid(.mtry = 5, .ntree = 1000)
...
```

This does not error like randomForest does.

Comment: You should tag this with [caret] too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The grid should be a simple data frame with a column called `.mtry`. The code

```
 g = createGrid("cforest", len, data)
```

will generate that for you. If you want to specify `ntree` you just pass a `controls` object in as another argument to `train` but leave out `mtry`:

```
 mod <- train(Species ~ ., data = iris,
              method = "cforest",
              controls = cforest_unbiased(ntree = 10))
```

`caret` takes care of changing `mtry` for you.

Max